# Iterator in For Loop Removes Odds Not Evens

Tags: java, arraylist

I wrote this to remove all even numbers from an ArrayList, but it is unexpectedly doing the opposite and removing the odds.

**Code:**

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //filled 1-1000

protected void eliminateEven()
    {
        x = 0;
        for(Iterator<String> iter = arr.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        {
            iter.next();

            if(x % 2 == 0)
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println(arr);
    }
```

By the way, "arr" is an ArrayList prefilled to 1000. I would appreciate some help with this, so I can figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: You are removing items that have an even index from the list, not items that have an even value.  If you want to remove things based on their value, you have to check what that value is, not just check the loop counter.

Comment: give definition of `arr` and how it is filled ;) remove off indexes ? because odd element seems  not possible if they are String

Comment: I apologize. Adding definitions...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a list of `Integer` and an iterator of `String`. That doesn't make a lot of sense. But assuming they are strings, you need to convert to integers before checking if they are even.

You don't need to maintain the `x` index: just check the value of the iterator:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(iter.next()) % 2 == 0)
    iter.remove();
```

Or, even simpler in Java 8:

```
arr.removeIf(i -> Integer.valueOf(i) % 2 == 0);
```

As an aside, I would suggest a `while` loop would be a bit clearer than a `for` loop without a `next` clause:

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping the first item by calling

```
iter.next()
```

before actually checking the condition, then your iterator is actually one 'position' ahead than your 'index', that's why it is removing the odd elements instead of the even as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple outer loop it would be like this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = arr.iterator();
int x = 1;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.next();
    if(x % 2 == 0) {
        iter.remove();
    }
    x++;
}
```

Of course, there exist more graceful solutions.